# Using Adobe Reader commands to manipulate a PDF using python

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, reader, adobe-reader

I would like to secure PDF files the same way it's possible using Adobe Reader: it's possible to open the file without the password, but copying, changing the document, page extraction, printing in high-resolution etc. are not allowed.
I know that there is a way to encrypt a PDF file using PyPDF2, using this code (for the curious only, taken from https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/06/07/an-intro-to-pypdf2/), but it asks for a password before opening the contents and then copying is still possible:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def encrypt(input_pdf, output_pdf, password):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input_pdf)

    for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    pdf_writer.encrypt(user_pwd=password, owner_pwd=None, 
                       use_128bit=True)
    with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as fh:
        pdf_writer.write(fh)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    encrypt(input_pdf='introduction.pdf',
            output_pdf='encrypted.pdf',
            password='blowfish')
```

But is there a way to secure a PDF using Adobe Reader commands? I've searched and I failed. Does anybody know how to do it? Hope somebody can help!

Comment: Adobe Reader does not have that functionality. You need Adobe Acrobat Pro for this. (Which is, presumably, why you could not find how to do it. That ought to have given you a hint...)

Comment: The `user_pwd` parameter contains the password in question. Have you tried setting it to `""` or `None`?

Comment: Thanks, guys and sorry for the confusion, it is possible, I answered the question in the comment below!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible after all!
The code above works, all you need is to change the user password to empty string, set an owner password and change one line in the `PyPDF2`'s `pdf.py` file from:

```
# permit everything:
P = -1
```

to:

```
# permit everything:
P = -3904
```

This block all changing, copying etc. for the encrypted PDF :)